# how many atlas's get loaded when using scene editor and sktexture()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, sktexture

Building a 2d platformer game and I build out my levels visually in the scene editor of the sks files.

I store my textures in atlas folders, not within the xcassets. In the scene editor my levels use images from the atlas files. Assuming we are talking about 1 atlas folder that atlas get's loaded into memory when the scene loads.

Within code I change images according to specific things using:

SKTexture(imageNamed: "Example")

My question is when I use this SKTexture() function, does it know that there is an atlas already loaded in memory with that texture, or does it load a new atlas into memory to get the image?

Thanks for any information.

Comment: Atlases are only loaded once and then cached.  When you stop using all the textures in an atlas, it gets freed from memory.  Next time you use a texture, it will reload the atlas again.

Comment: So when I call sktexture() it just searches memory first prior to searching the disk?

Comment: Yes,  except it now creates new sktexture objects instead of passing a pointer,  the texture is still the same memory, just the sktexture is a new instance

Comment: I’ll usually do spritenode.texture = sktexture()  within code. Does this also create an sktexture object? Instead of a pointer? Is there a way to get it to be a pointer

Comment: @Knight0fDragon If I have multiple atlas files that have the same image "example.png" and 1 atlas is loaded into memory that caintains that image. When I call sktexture(imageNamed: "example"), will it pull from memory or could it potentially load a different atlas that also has the same image.

Comment: I dont think you can have images of the same name in 2 atlases, the system should yell at you

Comment: @Knight0fDragon there is no error if in different atlas folders. I do my atlas folders manually...

Comment: You should still see an error somewhere along the way,  I do bot know what the behavior is if it doesn’t